# Efficiently creating a transition matrix for a large data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, transition

I have a table in R that I need to build an empirical transition matrix (of counts) in R.

The data looks like this:

```
ExplicitRoll               ExplicitRoll_EOM
No Change                      No Change
No Change                      1-> 3
No Change                      No Change
NoChangeMonthOfPayoff      NoChangeMonthOfPayoff
No Change                      Entry
NoChangeMonthOfPayoff      NoChangeMonthOfPayoff
No Change                     No Change
....
```

This table is very large and has many types  of other colum entries (for instance `1->3`, `charged off` etc). The first column represents month t and the second column represents t-1.

Is there a way to very efficiently cound how many transitions from one state to the next? For reference, the entire data set is 18M rows.

Thank you!

Comment: How come your columns are identical but you claim that one is the lagged of the other?

Comment: They are not in order. This is simply a random sampling of columns. Most of the rows have no change in status. I have modified 2 rows to help illustrate. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table()` creates such an incidence matrix. You can convert it to dataframe with `as.data.frame.matrix`. Example:

```
df = data.frame(Col1 = c("A","B","C","D","A","B","E"),Col2 = c("B","C","D","B","B","E","A"))
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))

  A B C D E
A 0 2 0 0 0
B 0 0 1 0 1
C 0 0 0 1 0
D 0 1 0 0 0
E 1 0 0 0 0
```

---

18 million rows:

```
df = data.frame(Col1 = sample(letters,18000000,replace = T),sample(letters,18000000,replace = T))

a = Sys.time()
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))
Sys.time()-a
```

Time difference of 0.5171118 secs. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it can, see my added example.

Comment: Convinced! Thank you!

Comment: @Florian I think you meant `as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))` .   instead of 
`as.data.frame.matrix(table(dt))`

Comment: @JasonBaik, yes indeed, thanks for notifying me :) I edited the answer accordingly.